# An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file

Tags: sql, asp.net

Estoy trabajando un login en ASP pero cuando hago la consulta me lanza el siguiente error:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C: \Users\Jose Pablo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\ProyectoFinal\App_Data\shopping.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

**Error de código fuente:**

> Línea 20:     protected void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>
> Línea 21:     {
>
> Línea 22:         con.Open();
>
> Línea 23:         SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
>
> Línea 24:         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

Este es mi `código`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class admin_adminlogin : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\Jose Pablo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\ProyectoFinal\App_Data\shopping.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
int i = 0;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from admin_login where username '"+t1.Text+"' and password '"+t2.Text+"' ";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
    Response.Write(i);
    con.Close();

}
}
```

Comment: El error indica claramente que la base de datos ya existe. ¿Cúal es tu pregunta?

Comment: Tengo únicamente una base de datos con ese nombre, mi pregunta es como solucionar eliminar (si existiera) esa base de datos para que no persista el error.

Comment: Ya cree otro base de datos con diferente nombre y me sigue lanzando el mismo error.